# Deaths by falling coconuts

Tags: data-request, medical, global

I am looking for the number of deaths caused by the natural fall of coconuts from trees each year.

- Number  of deaths each year worldwide, estimated if needed
- Bonus for extra information about each death, such as country and date
- Must exclude coconuts that have been thrown rather than felt from the tree normally
- Data for recent years, though further historical data is good too if available

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_coconut) only talks about separated incidents, without giving any statistics.

Comment: So, going on vacation?

Comment: I suspect those data (if any) to be lacunary. You will have to resort to specific methods to process them, as in [What are detailed references explaining Hugo Steinhaus early “data science” work?](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/8587/what-are-detailed-references-explaining-hugo-steinhaus-early-data-science-work)

Comment: Have you checked the references on this Wiki article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_by_coconut in case there is somewhere a dataset?

Comment: the aforementioned page on Wikipedia has clearly delineated habitat area, which can help OP to create list of countries/jurisdictions

once list is elaborated, one can collect medical casualties statistics per country, join them in one table and publish here link to new dataset

Comment: @silpol: Wikipedia also has an article called "Deaths in 1954". Using it do do statistics reveals that the number of people who died in 1954 is 117. That's because Wikipedia information is about notable/documented events, and inappropriate for statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[National Electronic Injury Surveillance System](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/) (NEISS) is a great resource for free-text details of emergency-room visits, including fatalities.

Unfortunately (for you), years 2009-2015 show cutting-based coconut-related injuries (plus one allergy):

[image]

2015

> 46 YOF WAS CUT W/KNIFE WHILE CUTTING A **COCONUT**. DX:  FINGER LAC W/DIGITAL NERVE INJURY.
>
> 31YOM CUTTING A **COCONUT** WITH A KNIFE AND SUSTAINED A FINGER LACERATION
>
> 53YOM WAS CUTTING **COCONUT** AND LAC FINGER WITH KNIFE
>
> 72YM FOR AF, WAS CUTTING THE BOTTOM OF **COCONUT** TO MAKE BIRDHOUSE
>   WHEN IT SPUN RUNNING HIS HAND ON THE TOP OF THE TABLESAW>>LAC

2014

> 34YOM CUT LEFT FINGER WITH A KNIFE WHILE CUTTING A **COCONUT**, LACERATION OF LEFT THUMB

2013

> 24  YOM WAS TRYING TO CUT A **COCONUT** WITH A KNIFE AND CUT HIS HAND. DX HAND LAC
>
> 13 YO MALE SLICING A **COCONUT** AND CUT FINGER WITH A KNIFE.  DX LACERATION FINGER

2012

> 9 YOF STABBED HAND W/A KNIFE WHILE OPENING A COCONUT. DX:  R HAND LAC .5 CM.
>   9YO M OPENING A **COCONUT** WITH A SHARP BLADE AND POKED FINGER  DX PUNCTUR E WOUND TO FINGER
>
> 46 YO M, C/O CUT TO LT HAND, WAS TRYING TO OPEN A **COCONUT** W/ A KNIFE WH EN HE ACCIDENTALLY CUT HIMSELF, DX HAND LACERATION
>
> 27YOF W/ALLERGY TO COCONUT, MOTHER USED **COCONUT** ROOM DEODORIZER PT. HAD SOB AND CHEST PAIN.
>
> 43 YOF, PT WAS USING KNIFE TO CUT A **COCONUT**, KNIFE SLIPPED & STABBED L T HAND. DX; LAC LT HAND

2011

> None!

2010

> CUT WITH KNIFE WHILE CUTTING **COCONUT**. 35 YO F LACERATION L HAND #
>
> 36 YOM WAS CUT W/KNIFE WHILE PEELING **COCONUT**. DX:  L HAND LAC 3 CM.
>
> 41YOF DRILLING A HOLE IN A **COCONUT** AND BIT R AND PUNCTURE HAND

2009

> PT CUTTING A **COCONUT** WITH A KNIFE AND SUSTAINED A LACERATION TO FINGER
>
> PT WAS CUT W/KNIFE  WHILE CUTTING **COCONUT**. DX:  R HAND LAC.
>
> PT TRYING TO OPEN A **COCONUT** WITH A HAMMER STRUCK SELF IN THE HEAD WITH THE HAMMER CLOSED HEAD INJURY
>
> DX LAC REPAIR/TETANUS BOOSTER: LAC TO PALM OF L HAND W PAR'G KNIFE W CUT'G ON **COCONUT** THIS EVEN'G
>
> PT CUT FINGER WITH A KNIFE WHILE CUTTING OPEN A **COCONUT** AT HOME TODAY DX// LEFT INDEX FINGER LAC

So, probably there are very few recorded falling-coconut accidents, and, similar to shark attacks, most would be then cataloged on Wikipedia.

---

By the way, you can [download individual years as XLSX](http://www.cpsc.gov/en/Research--Statistics/NEISS-Injury-Data/), or you can export year-by-year by search the [Query Tool](http://www.cpsc.gov/cgibin/NEISSQuery/home.aspx) without any parameters, and then exporting CSV, or this data has been [exported to R-stats](https://github.com/hadley/neiss).

Comment: If I understand correctly it is the data for USA only, but I guess it is the best quality data I will ever get :-)